# Given 2 positions (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) print the sum of all elements within the area of rectangle in O(1) time

Tags: arrays, matrix

A 2D matrix is given to you. Now user will give 2 positions (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), 
which is basically the upper left and lower right coordinate of a rectangle formed within the matrix. 
You have to print sum of all the elements within the area of rectangle in O(1) running time. 
Now you can do any pre computation with the matrix. 
But when it is done you should answer all your queries in constant time.

Example : consider this 2D matrix

```
1 3 5 1 8 
8 3 5 3 7 
6 3 9 6 0
```

Now consider 2 points given by user (0, 2) and (2, 4). 
Your solution should print: 44. 
i.e., the enclosed area is

```
5 1 8 
5 3 7 
9 6 0
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What language are you using?

Comment: I'm able to figure out how to get the sum of submatrices but unable  to figure out how to get the rectangle sum.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question seems to be related to homeworks, i am just posting a clue... It is a formula that may inspire you :

[image: formula]

What does this sum of terms represent ?

Rewrite your problem using mathematical tools, indexes like `i` and `j` ...

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can also help:
[image: courtosy of: http://www.techiedelight.com/calculate-sum-elements-sub-matrix-constant-time/]

courtosy of: http://www.techiedelight.com/calculate-sum-elements-sub-matrix-constant-time/